# springboot use @async to execute task sometimes appear timeout

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous

I write a project about forwarding an HTTP request with the spring-boot framework.
Sometimes in load test (about 100 concurrency request), it appears a long delay time e.g I response the HTTP request in 0.01s, but post the async request after 10 seconds.
I use the default Spring Boot setup, is this mean the Spring Boot will put the async method to ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.class? The default core size is 1, so it will be blocked in a load test?

sorry for my poor English
Any help will be appreciated

```
@Override
@Async
public void rabbit(String jsonString, String path) {
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(jsonString, requestHeaders);
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<String> postRespone = template.postForEntity(path, requestEntity, String.class);
    logger.info("PostApduScripts success!" + "\tResult:" + postRespone.getBody());
}
```

---

```
public class ThreadPoolTaskExecutor extends ExecutorConfigurationSupport       implements AsyncListenableTaskExecutor, SchedulingTaskExecutor {
private final Object poolSizeMonitor = new Object();
private int corePoolSize = 1;
private int maxPoolSize = 2147483647;
private int keepAliveSeconds = 60;
private int queueCapacity = 2147483647;
private boolean allowCoreThreadTimeOut = false;
private TaskDecorator taskDecorator;
private ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor;

public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor() {
}

public void setCorePoolSize(int corePoolSize) {
    synchronized(this.poolSizeMonitor) {
        this.corePoolSize = corePoolSize;
        if (this.threadPoolExecutor != null) {
            this.threadPoolExecutor.setCorePoolSize(corePoolSize);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: honestly it's not clear, you are using `@async` method to make API call in spring boot application with custom `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`, okay, then any problem at load test?

Comment: Hmm, you are using wrapper around `RestTemplate`, and by default `Spring Boot` uses Tomcat, and their nature are synchronous. If you want asynchronous Spring Boot, look at Spring WebFlux - https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactive-rest-service/

Comment: You can add to your restTemplate `.setConnectTimeout(...)`  `.setReadTimeout(...) ` to add more time but for using the real asyn , i recommand you to use `webClient` ratherThan `restTemplate` , means `spring webFlux`

Comment: @Deadpool Thanks for answering.I use the default ThreadPoolTaskExecutor I think.Problem is I receive the http request,then execute the async method ,do the response .But the async method execute after a long time.

Comment: @BSeitkazin Thanks for your advice,I will take a look at the docs

Comment: okay if i understand correctly `@async` method is taking long time, do you why? i can only see API call in it, does API call taking long time for response?

Comment: @Deadpool API call takes a little time.So I think the problem maybe in the threadpool

Comment: @TinyOS I have checked the webFlux ,it's in spring-boot 2.0. Now I use spring-boot 1.5.7.RELEASE .The new feature is very interesting,use functional java and netty ,I will use it in my next project.